# How can I use jQuery.validate without submitting the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have read several of the other posts about this and still no go. Trying to keep it real simple. I need to validate sections of a form that are being hidden/shown in a jQuery accordion before final submit. I have been using `jquery.validate.js` for a long time and as long as I validate on `submit` all is good, but now when I try to validate on button `click`  it is not working.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery().ready(function(){
    var demo = $(".demo").accordion({
        header: '.header',
        event: false
    });

    var nextButtons = $([]);
    $("h3.header", demo).each(function(index) {
        nextButtons = nextButtons.add($(this)
        .next()
        .children(":button")
        .filter(".next, .previous")
        .click(function() {
            demo.accordion("activate", index + ($(this).is(".next") ? 1 : -1))
        }));
    });

});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(".next").click(function(){
$("#test").validate({              
     rules: {
                     name: "required", // simple rule, converted to {required:true}
                     email: {// compound rule
                         required: true,
                         email: true
                     },
                     comment: {
                         required: true
                     }
                 },
                 message: {
                     comment: "Please enter a comment."
                 }
             });


});
</script>
    <div class="demo">
<form action="#" method="post" id="test">
  <fieldset>
<div id="accordion">
    <h3 class="header"><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
    <div class="sec1">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your 
full name" class="required" />
<input type="button" class="next" value="NEXT" />
    </div>
    <h3 class="header"><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
    <div class="sec2">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter 
your email address" class="required" />
<input type="button" class="next" value="NEXT" />
<input type="button" class="previous" value="Previous"/>
    </div>
    <h3 class="header"><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
    <div class="sec3">
    <label for="message">Message:</label>
    <textarea id="message" placeholder="What's on your 
mind?" class="required"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send message" />
    <input type="button" class="previous" value="Previous"/>
    </div>
      </fieldset>
</form>

</div>
</div><!-- End demo -->
```

Comment: this [POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703955/jquery-validation-before-ajax-submit/11704059#11704059) will help you.

Comment: Thanks Kundan for your reply. i am sorry but I don't see how it helps me. I have no onsubmit on my form tag and I am not checking for '("#test").validate' to return true for something to happen. i want to pass the values of my fields to the validator's functions for processing/evaluation. it seems like the click function attached to the button with the class of "next" is just not happening

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot initialize `validate()` *inside* a handler.  You initialize it inside the `document.ready` and use `.valid()` to test for validity.  A submit button is not required to validate the form in this case.

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11068130/594235):

[`.validate()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) is what initializes the Validation plugin on your `form`.

[`.valid()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) returns `true` or `false` depending on if your form is presently valid.

So within your `.click()` handler, you'd use `.valid()`, not `.validate()`, in conjunction with an `if` statement to test if form is valid...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").validate({  // initialize plugin on the form
         rules: {
         ...
         }
         ...
         // etc.
    });

    $(".next").click(function(){  // capture the click
        if($("#test").valid()){   // test for validity
            // do stuff if form is valid
        } else {
            // do stuff if form is not valid
        }
    });
});
```

See [docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) for more info.

Normally, you would have a `type="submit"` button within the `form` container and, in that case, would not need to capture any clicks as this is all done automatically.  This answer is tailored for the OP's specific case where a traditional `submit` button is not used.

**Side-note:**  All of your JavaScript can be contained within a *single* set of `<script></script>` tags.  Multiple sets of tags all strung together is unnecessary and superfluous.