# JQuery validation form but not `submit` button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm using the [JQuery.Validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)  to validate some fields in a form, but I don't want to use a `submit` button, I want to use just an `<input type="button">` and once clicked using `JQuery` I want to call my controller, the only thing is that it's not a `submit` button, so even if the fields are wrong or not validated it will call the controller even if the fields values are wrong, because I'm using the `.click()` event of `JQuery` when that button is clicked, I want when I have wrong values on the fields and the validation is showing an error message not to call my action controller even if the button is clicked, how can I reach this?
This is my `html` code:

```
<script src="~/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form action="post" class="rightform newsletter" id="formSubscription">
    <div class="title">
        <img src="http://ligresources.blob.core.windows.net/public/UK/Content/Images/newsletter.png" alt="">NEWSLETTER
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="txtFullName" name="fullName" placeholder="Full name" required>
    <input type="email" id="txtEmail" name="email" placeholder="Email address" required>
    <button type="button" id="btnSubscription" data-url="@Url.Action("SubscriptionEmail","Email")" style="background-color:#f66804;">SUBSCRIBE TO NEWSLETTER</button>                
</form>
```

This is the `JQuery.Validation plugin` code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#formSubscription").validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required:true,
                email:true
            },
            fullName: {
                required:true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: {
                required: "Please enter an email address",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And this is the JQuery function that I have for the moment to throw when the `btnSubscription` is `clicked`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubscription").click(function () {
        SendSubscription();          
    }),
    return false;
}),

function SendSubscription() {       
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: $("#btnSubscription").data("url"),
        data: { fullName: $("#txtFullName").val(), emailAddress: $("#txtEmail").val() },
        success: function () {
            alert("email sent")
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("An error occurred..")
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If you dont want to use submit button then you can call the functionality using  onfocusout event.

Comment: change one of your input to `type="email"`

Comment: @Endless you are right, I was testing and I forgot to change it again to email, it's done :)

Comment: just call the .valid() function on the form in your click handler

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098103/need-jquery-validate-without-submit

Comment: @Chase I've used your solution, it's very simple to use, if you could put it as an answer I will approve it so it will help the next readers too

Comment: @AlexGH I put in my answer for you.

Comment: Here is how i would have built a more generic example: https://jsfiddle.net/xy3k6qjj/ one that isn't so specific to your code... Also, it don't require any validation plugin since the submit event will not happen until it's valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you set up your `.validate()` all you need to do is call the `.valid()` method in your `.click()` handler. This is what submit does automatically, but you can call it manually with the `.valid()` method.

Answer (score 3):

you should use type `submit`, and then you can use the submitHandler in order to manage other things you want to do, like this:

```
$("#formSubscription").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    // do other things for a valid form
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

Take a loot at the documentation: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Answer (score 0):

put an if in the SendSubscription function:

```
if (yourValidationDidntPass) {
  //do whatever you want
}
else {
  $.ajax({...});
}
```